# Modulus Code Simplification

Tags: c++

I've came across something in Competitive Programming 2 book which I don't quite understand.
I'm quite new and tried to search the question but still no hope, maybe I'm blind.

```
index = (index+1)%n
```

is a simplification for

```
index++;
if(index>=n){
    index=0;
}
```

why is that? it didn't work out though.
source : competitive programming 2, page 12, shortcuts used for c/c++/java in programming.

Comment: Not the same, if index is already, for example 2*n + 5, if you increment 1 and calculate mod would be 6, but if you execute the second code would be 0.

Comment: Has anyone tried to profile it. My guess would be that the simplified version is slower. The mod operator, %, is really slow. The branch prediction on the other hand should almost always be correct, giving blazingly fast code for the original version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is simple, think about an array that is 3 long (ie `n` = 3). Start at 0 and work your way up:

```
start       calculation   next
0 : (0 + 1) % 3 : 1 % 3 : 1
1 : (1 + 1) % 3 : 2 % 3 : 2
2 : (2 + 1) % 3 : 3 % 3 : 0
```

What it is doing is looping over the indexes of the array of length `n` repeatedly, you might use it the following way

```
while (!done)
    index = (index+1)%n;
    //do something
    if (itWorked)
        done = true;
```

This could loop over the array performing some operation continuously and it would always provide the next in-bound index.

In terms of the second part, these two code segments are equivalent.

```
0 : ++0 < 3 : true : 1
1 : ++1 < 3 : true : 2
2 : ++2 < 3 : false : 0
```

So you can use either. Of course the second one is more readable.

Of course, this will not be the case if `index > n`, however, that is not really how this is intended to be used.

Comment: +1 The essential information (which has been left out by the author of the book) is that this is for finding the next element of an array of n size, and just for it

Answer (score 0):

The statement is wrong.
It is only true if 0 <= index < n before execution of

```
index = (index+1)%n
```

e.g., index = 5, n = 4

The result of the first program is

```
(5 + 1) % 4 = 2
```

The result of the second program is 0

As for why the two programs are equivalent, the systematic way is to find all cases of initial conditions.
Assume 0 <= index < n, then there are only two cases

case 1. index + 1 == n

case 2. index + 1 < n

if you put values from two cases into two pieces of program, you'll see their results are equivalent for all possible inputs satisfying the assumptions. That is why they claim one is the simplification of another.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation (only adding one), the modulo operator version will give the same result. Essentially, what is happening is that index is being incremented first (because of the brackets). Using the modulo operator, we then check the remainder of index and n. When index and n are the same (equivalent to `if(index>=n)`), the result will be 0 (equivalent to `index=0`).

This example could cause problems however, since it will not work if you are incrementing by more than 1, since index % n, while n > index is > zero (NOT equivalent to `index=0`). It also assumes that index starts less than n, which is also dangerous. Just make sure you understand that before using code like this.

This code is basically the author trying to do clever things, but instead ends up making less readable code, which only functions correctly under very specific starting conditions, which can fail silently. Use this as an example of what not to do.